# How to remove an Ad when user clicked on it? To protect multiple times clicking on same ad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This code removes div containing ad according to set time:

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   setTimeout(function(){
   $('#adbox').remove();
   }, 5000);
   </script>
```

This code hides ad after button click:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hide").click(function(){
   $("#adbox").hide();
   });
   });
   </script>
   <button id="hide">skip ad &#10060;</button>


   <div id="adbox"> ad code goes here </div>
```

Is it possible to make a script to remove or hide div containing ad after ad click?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console log?

Comment: what was the issue...?

Comment: my ad clicks getting invalid cuz people clicking ad multiple times!

Comment: Have you tried `$('#adbox').click(function() { $(this).hide(); });`?

Comment: w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro Please copy paste this in that editor. See if its working or not? Cuz when i click ads it wont hide. :( This ad code will work in that editor: <div id="ads"><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> <!-- Homepage Leaderboard --> <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:50px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1993393738408076" data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins> <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script></div>

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can do:

```js
$('#adbox').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<div id="adbox"> ad code goes here </div>
```

Widhout jQuery:

```js
document.querySelector('#adbox').onclick = function() {
  this.style.display = 'none';
};
```

```html
<div id="adbox"> ad code goes here </div>
```

Comment: My apologies if I come across as being pedantic, but why use `onclick` instead of `addEventListener('click', function() { })`?

Comment: I like how you included a non-jquery alternative.

Comment: w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro Please copy paste this in that editor. See if its working or not? Cuz when i click ads it wont hide. :( This ad code will work in that editor: <div id="ads"><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> <!-- Homepage Leaderboard --> <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:50px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1993393738408076" data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins> <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` with your `hide()` function. Inside a Jquery callback, the `$(this)` value stand for the current element, so if you write `$('#ads').on('click', function(item) {});` the `$(this)`variable will point to the `$('#ads')` element, that's why we can call Jquery function on it.

```js
$('#ads').on('click', function(item) {
 $(this).hide();
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

#ads {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <div id="ads"></div>
</div>
```

Note here that most of the code is irrelevent, only the Javascript part is important.

Comment: If you are using Jquery, it does not matter what ads manager you use. Just point the `$('#ads')` to the div where the ad is and it will work.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro


Please copy paste this in that editor. See if its working or not?
Cuz when i click ads it wont hide. :(

This ad code will work  in that editor:
  <div id="ads"><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Homepage Leaderboard -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:50px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-1993393738408076"
data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>

Comment: You should never post client key on the internet.

Comment: its not mine, its from w3shools copied from their ad code.

Comment: I can't seams to make the ads appear either.

Comment: its not easy for me!